# Since measurement collapses wavefunction and everything is constantly interacting, how does uncollapsed wavefunction exist?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Interaction causes change and that change can be measured, so shouldn't everything be measured constantly

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/460855