# In the double slit experiment, would a gravity detector cause wave function collapse?

Tags: double-slit-experiment

In the double slit experiment, if a sufficiently sensitive instrument capable of detecting the gravity of the passing electron were used in place of a photon, would this cause wave function collapse?

I wonder about this because it could possibly obtain which-way information about the electron without directly interacting with it.

Comment: Regardless of whether this is practically possible, if the electron exerts a gravitational force on the detector, the detector also exerts a gravitational force on the electron, so there must be "direct interaction."

Comment: Closely related: [Why aren't particles constantly "measured" by the whole universe?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/460855) That question asks about the gravity effect, among other things.

Comment: +1 I have a hypothesis, whenever a wavefunction collapses to a particular state, like electron collapsing to a discrete position (~point particle), it should be associated with non-zero conformal curvature since in relativity, every localised source is associated with conformal curvature. So you can gravitationally verify that wavefunction has collapsed. I am not sure if it is possible the other way around